# Trigger event after slideUp or slideDown is completed

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a simple slideUp animation on an object.
I want to add attribute tag to the the element after animation completes.
How can i get this to work ?

```
if($(this).is(':visible')) {
  if(config.animate=='true')                    
    $(this).slideUp(options.animationTime);   //After animation ends do $(this).attr('shown','true');
  else 
    $(this).hide();             
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$(this).slideUp(options.animationTime, function() {
    $(this).attr('shown','true');
});
```

Comment: Forgot that you could pass stuff through slideUp when it completes...thanks for the answer. For those who like documentation, [here's the relevant link](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).